# Foreign Key Refers the Primary Key Columns of Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables like this:

Table 1 - CivilOffices

```
Id - Primary key
OfficeId - Foreign Key - refer to Office Table
Created Date
Location 
ParentOffice - Foreign Key - refer to Office Table
```

Table 2 - Offices

```
OfficeId - Primary key
Name
```

I want to query all the offices with their respective parent office name.
But when I tried to query this, the query returns the parent office id instead of parent office name.

Here is the query I used.

```
SELECT O.OfficeId, O.Name, CO.ParentOffice
FROM Offices As O
LEFT JOIN CivilOffices As CO
ON O.OfficeId=CO.OfficeId;
```

Here is the result

```
OfficeId | Name    | ParentOffice
---------------------------------
1        |Office1  |NULL
2        |Office2  |NULL
3        |Office3  |1
4        |Office4  |3
5        |Office5  |NULL
6        |Office6  |2
```

Instead, I want result something like this

```
---------------------------------
OfficeId | Name    | ParentOffice
---------------------------------
1        |Office1  |NULL
2        |Office2  |NULL
3        |Office3  |Office1
4        |Office4  |Office3
5        |Office5  |NULL
6        |Office6  |Office2
```

Comment: Join `Offices` again on `CO.ParentOffice`

Comment: I can't see an `OfficeName` column in your table `CivilOffices`, so where is the name coming from?

Comment: Good to see a well written, complete question.

Comment: Hmm, if that's the case @HoneyBadger this would be served better with a self referencing table; no need for 2 table here. Is redesigning your data an option here Areef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as follows:

```
SELECT
    co1.OfficeId,
    o1.Name,
    o2.Name AS ParentOffice
FROM Offices o1
LEFT JOIN CivilOffices co1
    ON o1.OfficeId = co1.OfficeId
LEFT JOIN Offices o2
    ON co1.ParentOffice = o2.OfficeId;
```

We do a self-join on the `CivilOffices` table to match each record with a potential parent.  Then, we use two separate joins to `Offices` to bring in the office name as well as possibly the parent office name, should the latter exist.

Answer (score 0):

You store the name of the office in the `Offices` table, so you need to access the `Offices` record which relates to the parent office to obtain its name.

For this just use a sub-query to extract the name of the parent office from the `Offices` table. If you needed more fields from the parent office you would then consider `left joining` it on, but for a single field a sub-query is straight-forward.

```
SELECT O.OfficeId, O.Name
  , (select O2.Name from Offices as O2 where O2.OfficeId = CO.ParentOffice) AS ParentOfficeName
FROM Offices AS O
LEFT JOIN CivilOffices AS CO ON O.OfficeId = CO.OfficeId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more `left join` with `offices` table to connect `parent office id` -

```
SELECT O.OfficeId, O.Name, CO.ParentOffice, O1.name
FROM Offices As O
LEFT JOIN CivilOffices As CO
  ON O.OfficeId=CO.OfficeId
LEFT JOIN Offices O1
  ON O1.officeid = CO.parentoffice;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.OfficeId
    ,  o.Name 
    ,  c.ParentOffice 
FROM Offices o
INNER JOIN CivilOffices co ON O.OfficeId = CO.OfficeId
OUTER APPLY 
            (
            SELECT o1.Name AS ParentOfficeName 
                ,  co1.ParentOffice 
            FROM Offices o1
            INNER JOIN CivilOffices co1 ON O.OfficeId = CO.ParentOffice
            WHERE O.OfficeId = CO1.ParentOffice
            ) c
```